# 2.4G signals over single antenna

Tags: wifi

I want to run run two different 2.4 GHz radio cards off of the same antenna. Is this possible? I was thinking of running both into a splitter and running a single cable to the antenna. The two radio cards are operating on different channels. Is this possible or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Probably not as well as you would like, if at all. And you'd greatly risk damage to your device.

Longer answer:

-A splitter's directionality is only as good as the reflectivity of the load (antenna). The return loss of a common antenna could be as high as 9 dB. So, you output from radio A at 20 dBm, you lose 0.5 dB through the splitter, you lose 9 dB at the reflection, your reflected signal is split back through the splitter, losing another 3.5 dB towards radio B. Which means you only have 17 dB of isolation (and this is very offhand. The actual directivity may be even worse).

So, your 20 dBm output A signal is hitting the front end of your radio B with a possible 3 dBm of power when it's in receive mode.

-Even if your radio survives, you need to look at the channel to channel rejection. It's a safe assumption that if radio A transmits, radio B will still be swamped and unable to successfully receive a signal.

So, if you have these two radios and are willing to sacrifice them for science, try it out. My semi-professional opinion is that it will either not work or, worse, break some radios.

edit: I'm assuming here that if you're trying to cut costs by using one antenna, you probably don't want to add the high, high cost of a diplexer.It might be possible, depending on what channels/frequency you're talking about, to get a diplexer.

Comment: Its not really about cutting out cost, it is about cutting out work. I run multiple lines of coax for multiple antennas. We have a underground tracking and communication system. We have nodes that run off of a fiber backhaul. At the nodes, we have 4 radios. 3 of which talk to phones and one that talks to other nodes for a wireless backhaul. We move these nodes pretty frequently. I am just trying to find ways to cut down on the time it takes to set these things up and move them. Running 500 ft less of coax every other night would help out a lot. I'm thinking a diplexer might work?

Comment: If cost is really not an issue, then you might be able to do something crazy like put a splitter at the output of each radio, put anti-parallel RF isolators with an active limiter on the receive side, then a combiner at the output of that circuit. Then, tie the enable pin of the active limiter of radio B to the TX enable output of radio A (if that pin exists. If not, you can use a power detector).

That would solve the "breaking the RX" issue but you'd basically be creating a 'dumb' version of TDMA where you're only protecting circuitry and not actually coordinating TX/RX windows.

Crazy.

Comment: FYI I don't recommend that approach. It'd be ugly if it even worked. I just think it would be interesting. You'd greatly reduce your receive sensitivity. You could even use a passive limiter to help protect your receiver but I think the active limiter is much neater!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's possible. I'm going to assume that your "radio cards" are Wi-Fi radios or something else which must each receive and transmit.

However, you can't simply connect both radios to the same antenna as you describe. If you do that, the transmitted power from one radio will render inoperable the receiver of the other radio. It's possible it just won't work, but in all likelihood you will break your radios. Receivers are designed to handle the extremely weak power received from a distant transmitter -- not the full power of a transmitter coupled directly to it.

What you need to solve this problem is a [diplexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diplexer). A diplexer is a 3-port device. One port goes to the antenna, then each of the remaining two ports goes to one of your radios, each on a different channel. The diplexer has within it filters which isolate the different frequencies of each channel, so each radio does not see the other.

Unfortunately, a diplexer with a frequency response steep enough to sufficiently isolate two 2.4 GHz Wi-Fi channels will be very expensive. A separate antenna is almost certainly a more viable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Generally not.  Even if they are using different channels, the broadband noise from one that is transmitting will desensitize the receiver of the other radio.  For example, suppose one radio transmits at 1 W (+30 dBm) and has and adjacent power ratio of 50 dB.  Then the noise in the adjacent channel is -20 dBm.  The receiver may have a general sensitivity of -80 dBm.  But obviously if there is a million times more noise power than signal, it's not going to receive anything!

Comment: This is what I figured, but was hoping it would work. Oh well. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it is possible. However, power splitters have losses. An ideal 1:2 splitter will have 3dB loss. Normal splitters have higher loss than that. See 
http://www.minicircuits.com/homepage/homepage.html

For some examples. Also, you can build one using 16.5Ohm resistors (for 50Ohm system).

Comment: Receiving the signal would be no problem with a splitter. Transmitting the power would saturate/overwhelm/break/confuse the other radio.

Comment: This is not an issue if they separate transmit and receive times (a TDMA scheme).

Comment: It's a reasonable guess the question involves Wi-Fi radios, two of which won't jointly employ any TDMA scheme. Also, were such a scheme to be employed, what would be the point of running two radios on separate channels?

Comment: Two wifi radios in the 2.4GHz band is a recipe for troubles. However, two (even 4) 802.15.4 (Zigbee) radios are something else. I had a design with 4 CC2520, which did not have any problems receiving on channel 1 (2405MHz) and transmitting on channels 13, 14 and 15 (2465 to 2475MHz).